# RUN IF ELSE STATEMENT in MYSQL to run different querys

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to run a query with an if else statement(if possible in MYSQL)

I want to: `SELECT id FROM user_name_table WHERE user_name = @name;`

If the result of the query returns null i want to insert **@name** to user_name_table and get the autoincrement generated id
i need to store this result in a variable to use it later in another insert query.

This is as far as i got, in this case if "Sam" exists will return the ID twice, if not it will return ID and '0'

```
SET @name = "Sam";

SELECT id, IF(id!=0, id, 0)
FROM user_name WHERE user_name = @name;
```

Comment: Do you run the query through an app? I mean like, are you building an app with this query part of the function?

Comment: Yes, i'm planning to run this on a stored procedure by just passing the user_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want duplicates for `name`, then add a unique constraint or index:

```
alter table user_name add constraint unq_user_name_name unique (name);
```

Then, if you want to insert a new name, you can simply use:

```
insert into user_name (name)
    values (@name);
```

This will return an error if there is a duplicate.  If you don't want an error, I would suggest:

```
insert into user_name (name)
    values (@name)
    on duplicate key update name = values(name);
```

Comment: Or `INSERT IGNORE` - https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/

Comment: @wally . . . `on duplicate key update` only ignores errors that are due to violations of unique constraints.  `insert ignore` ignores other errors, which I don't think is a good idea.